# IBM Worklight - Build failure: "There are multiple skins for android with the same name"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

While trying to build the android environment, the following error occurs:

> FWLST1040E: android build failed: There are multiple skins for android with the same name: android.phone

how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that in your Worklight project, you have only 1 skin folder with the same name, as well as in application-descriptor.xml

[image]